# Smart Face ActionBar Menu Icon Too Small

Tags: menuitem, smartface.io

**SmartFace MenuItem Icon is not coming up properly, How do i get the actual size or customize the icon?**

```
var productAdd = new SMF.UI.Android.MenuItem({
    id:"productAdd",
    //title:"Hide Me!",
    icon: "ic_action_new.png",
    showAsAction:SMF.UI.Android.ShowAsAction.always,
    onSelected:function(e){
        alert("Selected item id: " + e.id);
        Pages.MainPage.visible = false; // hides the menu item when clicked.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for supporting every device first of all , all the resource folders should be filled.

You can read more about from http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/anatomy-project

Also the icon Sizes are defined in the link belows;

http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html